# I can't seem to dereference an array correctly

Tags: arrays, perl, dereference

I'm not very adept at Perl, but I need to be able to do a sort on a multi-dimension array. I've been playing with some test code to try and get a better grasp on the concept, and I think I'm getting close, but I can't find the magic combination.

What I can't seem to do is dereference my arrays and get them to print correctly. I can seem to get just about everything in the world I need to know about these refrences except for the values in the arrays being referenced.

I'm getting my data from a tab-delimited flat file, so in my sample code, I'm mimicking that by creating multiple arrays via splits and then pushing them in to a single array. In practice, I'll be looping through the file, splitting on the tabs and pushing them in to the array as I go.

If there is a better way of going about this, I'm all ears. Each line in the flat file is a single record. I need to first sort by a date to get the oldest records to the top, and then do a secondary sort to group records by acct number. I've looked at several examples online, but not found anything that seems to work with the data I need to mimick.

```
my @s1 = split(/:/, 'X:Y:Z');
my @s2 = split(/:/, 'A:B:C');
my @s3 = split(/:/, 'Q:L:P:0');
my @s4 = split(/:/, 'U:E:G');

my @array = ();
push(@array, \@s1);
push(@array, \@s2);
push(@array, \@s3);
push(@array, \@s4);

print "@array\n";

my @sorted = sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } @array;

print "\n";
foreach $thingy (@sorted)
{
    print @thingy . "\n"; #result: number 0
    print $thingy . "\n"; #result: reference
    #print ${$thingy} . "\n"; #result: 'Not a scalar reference' error
    print ${@thingy} . "\n"; #result: file name (???)
    print @{$thingy} . "\n"; #result: length of the array referenced
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you might want to consider something like this: `my @array = map [split /:/], qw(X:Y:Z A:B:C Q:L:P:0 U:E:G)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should always put `use strict;` at the top of your program.  That will catch numerous errors early.

The last line in your `foreach` loop is the one that dereferences `$thingy` correctly.  But since you've put `@{$thingy}` on the left-hand side of the `.` (string concatenation) operator, the array is in scalar context, and arrays in scalar context evaluate to their size.  Just say:

```
print "@{$thingy}\n";
```

to get the elements of `@$thingy` separated by spaces, or in general

```
print join('|', @{$thingy}), "\n";
```

if you want to use another separator, like the vertical bar character.  You can also just say

```
print @{$thingy}, "\n";
```

to print the elements with no separator at all.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed.  Sometimes, I have a hard time deciding if Perl is fun or not.  It's got some of the craziest nuances I've seen. I would have never guessed that that was my problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`@thingy` is undeclared and undefined (and unnecessary).

Use two nested loops to

1. iterate over your array with array-references
2. and in each loop then iterate over the items in that referenced array.

Like this

```
foreach my $array_ref (@sorted)
{
    foreach my $item (@{$array_ref}) {
        print $item, ",";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

The expression `@{$array_ref}` will dereference your array reference. It is used like an array then.

Addition:

You could replace

```
my @s1 = split(/:/, 'X:Y:Z');
my @s2 = split(/:/, 'A:B:C');
my @s3 = split(/:/, 'Q:L:P:0');
my @s4 = split(/:/, 'U:E:G');

my @array = ();
push(@array, \@s1);
push(@array, \@s2);
push(@array, \@s3);
push(@array, \@s4);
```

with

```
my @array = ();
push(@array, map { [split(/:/, $_)] } qw(X:Y:Z A:B:C Q:L:P:0 U:E:G));
```

If the sorting needs two criteria (the primary one at the first index and the secondary one at the second index) it can be written like this:

```
my @sorted = sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] 
                             ||
                    $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] 
                  } @array;
```

Comment: Like I said in my original post, this was just a test script I as playing with before I go trying to insert this code in to my main script.  So all the arrays and pushes will be handled better in the actual script.  I was just throwing something dirty in to mimic my situation and I included the code in to the snippet here for clarity.  But I did also want to say thanks for the primary/secondary sort code as well.  I hadn't seen that anywhere yet in my searches trying to just get the sort to work.  That was going to be my next challenge, but you made it easy on me.  I've tested it and it works!

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is add this to your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Then you will get the warning:

```
Global symbol "@thingy" requires explicit package name
```

Which means that `@thingy` is not defined. In perl, `$thingy` and `@thingy` count as separate variables.

Another way to create your array is to use anonymous arrays, like this:

```
push @array, [ split(/:/, 'X:Y:Z') ];
push @array, [ split(/:/, 'A:B:C') ];
...
```

Then you won't have to create throwaway variables. Or with a file like the one you describe (`\t` is tab):

```
while (<>) {
    push @array, [ split /\t/, $_ ];
}
```

A way to sort on multiple columns, from perlmonks:

```
my @a = ([1,2], [3,4]);
my @b = sort {

    $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] || # the result is -1,0,1 ...
    $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]    # so [1] when [0] is same

} @a;
```

http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=674374

Of course, this assumes numerical values in your fields. Otherwise use `cmp`.

To print:

```
for my $ref (@array) {
    my $i = 0;
    for my $value (@$ref) {
        print $value; 
        print "," if ($i++ < $#$ref); # comma delimited
    }
    print "\n"; # end of record
}
```